# OPtimizing yii2 mysql performance when performing writes

Tags: php, yii2

I have an orders app whereby orders are added and later an email is sent to the order users like this

```
if(Yii::$app->request->post()){


    //assign model attributes
    if($model->save()){
        return [
                  status:true ///notifies the frontend that saved successifully
                ]

          //the below processes are time consuming hence i would like them to queue
          $this->sendEmail($model->orderuser);
          $this->sendSMS($model->user_no) 
      }

   }
```

After model is saved, i would like to send email and sms but these sometimes takes quite sometime hence i would like return statement to notify that the process is complete then send mail and sms later

In the above architecture after return statement the others dont get executed?

When i add them before the return statement the process takes some valuable seconds, how can i execute my plan after return statement

Comment: i'd save them in a queue and write a cronjob that processed said queue

Comment: do you have an idea on how to work with queue in yii2, i saw one in laravel but have no clue on how to implement this in yii2

Comment: If you intend to use Queue then there's a recent extension released which you can use: http://www.yiiframework.com/news/141/yii-2-queue-extension-released/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `try` / `catch` block on `$model->save()`

```
//assign model attributes
try {
    $model->save();
} catch (yii\db\Exception $e) {
    throw new \yii\web\HttpException(405, 'Error saving model');
} catch (ErrorException $e) {
    throw new \yii\web\HttpException(405, 'Error saving model');
}
$this->sendEmail($model->orderuser);
$this->sendSMS($model->user_no);
```

Comment: 1. There's catch exception from Yii1, he have Yii2
2. There's no point in `try/catch` here (of course he should use it!), but it's not solving his problem. He wan't to do this asynchronous, so he have to prepare queue system.

Comment: @Yupik   . thanks  .. correct .. wrong refrence  ..  i have update the answer  ..